# Sum of $n6^{n}z^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm going mad calculating the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n6^{n}z^{n-1}$. I proceeded in this way: $\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(6z)^n$ and I'd like to figure out a geometric serie, but how can I take that $n$ factor to the exponent? Thankyou!

Comment: Think about derivatives. The derivative adds such a factor n usually.

Comment: Another possibility: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series.

Comment: @peter.petrov you're right, but I can't figure out how to pass from the derivative (I know $nz^{n-1}$ is the derivative of $z^{n}$) to $6^{n}d/dz(z^n)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\;|z|<1\;$ :

$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\stackrel{\text{differentiation}}\implies\frac1{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}\implies$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(6z)^n=\frac{6z}{(1-6z)^2}\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;|6z|<1\iff |z|<\frac16$$

Comment: But at the end you've $n(6z)^n$, how can you reach your conclusion?

Comment: Just put $\;w:=6z\;$ and it's all the same.

Comment: But I can't understand all the last term: how you pass from the derivative to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(6z)^n$

Comment: @lucad93 Just substitute $\;6z\;$ instead of $\;z\;$ in the second equality in the first line, and multiply there both sides by $\;6z\;$, and that's exactly the first equality in the second line.